# React Native child component does not receive updated state from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

I am trying to implement an app login screen where user enters username and password, and the app would retrieve a Json web token to be stored in application state for managing their account on the server. Now, my App.js looks like the following

```
const RootStack = StackNavigator(
{
  LoginPage:{screen:LoginPage},
  HomePage:{screen:HomePage},
},
{headerMode:'none'},
);

export default class App extends Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {token:'not available yet'}
}


updateState = async(u,p) => {
    try {
        let token = await this.getToken(u,p);
        let merchantInfo = await this.getMerchantInfo(token);

        this.state = {token: token, merchantInfo}
        console.log(this.state)
        console.log('our token state is '+ this.state.token)
        console.log("our merchantinfo state is "+this.state.merchantInfo.name)
    }
    catch (error) {console.log(error);}
}



// update the state of merchant using authToken
getMerchantInfo = async(authToken) => {
    var options = {
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        "authorization": "Bearer " + authToken,
        "content-type": "application/json"
        }
    }

    try {
        let response = await fetch('http://example.com/merchants/',options);
        let responseJson = await response.json();
        return responseJson;
    } catch (error) {console.error(error);}
}

// send over the username and password to server to retrieve an authToken
getToken = async(u,p) => {
    console.log('username is: '+u+' password is: '+p)
    var options = {
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": JSON.stringify({
            "email": u,
            "password": p,
        }),
    };

    try {
        let response = await fetch('http://example.com/merchants/login',options);
        let responseJson = await response.json();
        return responseJson.token;
    } catch (error) {console.error(error);}
}


render() {
    return (<RootStack screenProps= {this.state} />)
}
}
```

and my HomePage.js looks like the following

```
export default class HomePage extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {isReady: false};
console.log ('HomePage gets this token state: ' + this.props.screenProps.token)
}


render() {
return (
  <Container>
    <Header hasTabs>
      <Left />
      <Body>
        <Title>my app</Title>
      </Body>
      <Right>
        <Button transparent onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginPage')}>
          <Text>Logout</Text>
        </Button>
      </Right>
    </Header>

    <Tabs>
      <Tab heading="Issue">
        <IssueTab />
      </Tab>
      <Tab heading="Redeem">
        <RedeemTab />
      </Tab>
      <Tab heading="Settings">
        <SettingsTab />
      </Tab>
    </Tabs>
  </Container>
);
}
}
```

When I console.log(this.state.token) in App.js, I get the correct JWT token from my server:

```
our token state is ayJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.fgJuYW3lIjoibG92ZXNoYWNrIiwiZW1haWwiOiJhQGIuY29tIiwiaW1hZ2UiOiJ4cGxvYWRzL0RlZmF1bHQucG8vIiwibWVyY2hhbnLJZCI6IjViMDBjZGZlNzMwODA4NmE0YjZiOWM3NSIsImlhdCI6MTUyNzgwMjU1MywiZXhwIjoxNTU5MzYwMTUzfQ.0QQStfMyDcmYeqeFToei5M4Q35dj43S05NiI0uosXTg
```

However, when I console.log(this.props.screenProps.token) in HomePage.js, I get the initial state:

```
HomePage gets this token state: not available yet
```

I have tried componentWillReceiveProps and a few other approaches from doing searches on here, but nothing works for my situation. How do i get the updated state from App.js from HomePage.js in my situation?

This is my very first post here on StackOverflow. Cheers and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

State can only be set directly, like `this.state = { some: 'state' }`, inside of a constructor. Outside of the constructor you have to go through the setter `this.setState`. `setState` triggers a rerender and the new state will be passed down as expected. See the state docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html).

```
...
 updateState = async(u,p) => {
        try {
            let token = await this.getToken(u,p);
            let merchantInfo = await this.getMerchantInfo(token);

            this.setState({token: token, merchantInfo})
        }
        catch (error) {console.log(error);}
    }
...
```

Comment: i tried using setState as you suggested, and now neither App.js nor HomePage.js are getting "state is not available yet" in console.log....

Comment: Need to call `updateState`, it's not being called anywhere. Fetch usually occurs inside of the lifecycle method `componentDidMount`.

Comment: So `componentDidMount = async () => { await updateState(this.props.u, this.props.p) }` would do the trick. Assume u and p are username and password, you'd need to pass them as props this this component.

Comment: i tried adding componentDidMount = async () => {await updateState(this.props.screenProps.token)} in HomeScreen.js and it is still telling me the initial 'state not available yet'

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous, so the `console.log` statements after `this.setState` are going to print the current state not the next state that is being set. What is the output from `console.log(this.state)` if you put it in render? Should be `{token:'not available yet'}` for the initial render then once the component mounts and `updateState` (and this.setState within updateState) resolves `this.state` should equal `{token: token, merchantInfo}`.

Comment: when i put it in HomePage.js render, it gets this HomePage gets this token state: [object Object]

Comment: When printing JSON objects you need to use JSON.stringify in react native, so `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state))`

Comment: HomePage gets this token state: {"token":"not available yet"}

Comment: On the first render yes. Then once componentDidMount fires in App.js, and fetch/setState successfully resolve then that value should change. Constructors fire once in the lifecycle of a component, so you won't see that the prop has changed unless you are checking that value in render. Move that console.log in HomePage to the render method then the updated value should print out when state changes in App.js

Comment: Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

I am getting this in my console warning about the setState here in                 
    this.setState({token: token, merchantInfo})
and yeah, console.log in HomePage render() still doesnt print the updated state